# Use of just while(x)

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

/* Function Declaration
int pal(int x); */
/*Declaring Second Function*/

int rev(int x);

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    clrscr();

    printf("Enter The Number Which You Want To Check Is Palindrome Or Not\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    b = rev(a);
    printf("%d", b);

    if(b == a) {
        printf("%d Is A Palindrome Number", a);
    } else {
        printf("%d Isn't A Plaindrome Number", a);
    }

    getch();
    return(0);
}

int rev(int x)
{
    int d = 0;

    while(x) {
        d = d * 10 + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    return(d);
}
```

I didn't get the use of `while(x)` statement. I mean, we attach some condition with while loop i.e. `while(x!=0)`, so what does standalone `while(x)` means.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`while (x)` is the same as `while (x != 0)`

For an integral data type, 0 is `false` & everything else is `true`. So `while (x)` would evaluate to `while(true)` for all `x != 0`.

Similarly, you will also come across expressions like `while(!x)` or `if(!x)`

If `x` has value a non zero value, then `x` is `true` & `!x` is `false`. 
If `x` has value `0`, then `x` is `false` & `!x` is `true`.

So writing `(!x)` is the same as writing `(x == 0)`

You will also see similar usage with pointers. For a pointer `p`, `(p)` is the same as `(p != NULL)` and `(!p)` is the same as `(p == NULL)`.